# Horizontally shift boxplot bars' position using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to shift all bars in a boxplot horizontally on the plot (left or right). Is there a way I can adjust boxplots' x-axis position without changing the x-axis?

the code I am using to generate this boxplot is listed below,

```
plot <- ggplot(aes(y = SCORE, x = DATE, fill = CATEGORY), data = data_R1000) 
+ geom_boxplot(width=0.8) + ylim(20,100) + labs(title = "US_MARKETOR") 
+ theme(legend.position="bottom") 
+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)) 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ scale_fill_hue(c=50, l=85)
```

the results looks like this[image]

I have tried using position = position_dodge/position_jitter but none of them works. The output is a plot with multiple boxplot bars, and I have removed all background and grids. I want to shift these bars to the left side or right side of their default position.

Comment: Do exactly what? You have not offered even a glimpse into data_R1000. Seems likely that one would need to do some data manipulation or use of factor-levels. (Also seems likely that the calls to theme can be dropped.)

Comment: @DWin Sorry for the confusion. I have added a result figure to my original question. I am just wondering if there a way I can adjust the position of these box plots (move them to the left or right).

Answer (score 0):

Add `coord_flip()` to your code:

```
plot <- ggplot(aes(y = SCORE, x = DATE, fill = CATEGORY), data = data_R1000) 
+ geom_boxplot(width=0.8) + ylim(20,100) + labs(title = "US_MARKETOR") 
+ theme(legend.position="bottom") 
+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA)) 
+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
+ scale_fill_hue(c=50, l=85) 
+ coord_flip()
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question. What I am asking about is how to move these box plots to the left/right side of their original position. I don't what to flip them. Thank you!

Comment: If I understand right, you are trying to have the box plots on top of each other? It would be helpful if you could upload some sample data, even the first 100 rows of your data frame would help.